# SQL Server : multiple rows to one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table:

```
 TXT_Nr |   TXTL_LineNr    |    TXTL_String |   TXTL_Lgt|
 -------|------------------|----------------|-----------|
 10001  |   1              |    hello,      |    6      |
 10001  |   2              |    my name     |    7      |
 10001  |   N-lines can be |     ...        |    ...    |
```

Next result required:

```
TXT_Nr  | TXTL_String 
--------|---------------
10001   | hello, my name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using STUFF and GROUP BY method to concatenate string.

```
SELECT TXT_Nr , STUFF( (SELECT ',' + TXTL_String FROM #Table Inr WHERE 
Inr.TXT_Nr = otr.TXT_Nr FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM #Table Otr
GROUP BY TXT_Nr
```